# Saving and updating list stored in text file

Tags: c#

I'm using a text file that stores a list of objects and i am trying to create a button that will update an item in the text file based on what the user has entered in the form. The problem i have with the current code is that it overwrites the whole file and only shows one item in the list.

Below is my current code for saving to the text, thanks for your help.

```
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save everything in a dialog box
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        // Open the file and save the information
        Stream textOut = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textOut);

        FormToObject();
           string str = c.GetToString();
            writer.WriteLine(str);
            writer.Close();

    }

   private void FormToObject()
    {
        c.Brand = txtBrand.Text;
        c.Model = txtModel.Text;
        c.Year = txtYear.Text;
        c.Price = txtPrice.Text;
        c.NumMiles = txtNumMiles.Text;
        BodyCheck();
        GearCheck();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file and store the list of object as soon as your app initializes for example in App.xaml.cs file. Create a save method that manipulates the list of objects in memory and persists the collection to a file at the same time. That way every version of the collection is overwritten with a new collection.

Answer (score 0):

`Text file` is file contain sequential data. You cannot jump to specific record and update, you must to create new file (or buffer) *(1)* save the data till the record you want to update *(2)* update the record, and *(3)* continue with the rest of file.

Looks like, in your case, you're looking for `Binary file` that contains records and you can update specific record each time.

You can read about binary file in C# [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/binaryreader).

Answer (score 0):

First you would like to save everything from the file into a list. After that you would like to read everything from the textbox and finaly write everything into a textfile, correct?

Here's some pseudocode for this:

```
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save everything in a dialog box
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    // Open the file and save the information
    Stream textOut = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
    list<string> textfile = texout.ReadLines();
    foreach(item i in itemlist)
    {
        texfile.Add(i);
    }

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textOut);
    foreach(string str in texfile)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(str);
    }
    writer.Close();
}
```